# Add static files like html, css etc on publish alone in VS2017 .net framework project

Tags: azure, static, visual-studio-2017, include, publish

Need to include static files (angular build results) on visual studio 2017 Web API project, in publish alone, for azure deployment. Kindly advice.

Answer (score 0):

I'am not sure that you can do this using Visual Studio Publish tool for .net framework project ,
but I would recommend doing this manually using FTP.